# Is it possible to bypass constructors when instantiating objects in Android

Tags: android, constructor, objectinstantiation

Do Android have any way to instantiate objects without calling any of its constructors?

In Java, Sun have **sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.getReflectionFactory().newConstructorForSerialization()**, in .Net we have **[System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx)** but I was not able to find anything like that in the Android platform.

Comment: I'd be really curious to hear what the use case is for something like that.

Comment: Is your goal to deserialize so to speak objects that only have non empty constructors? This is an interesting request.

Comment: @Rich,Anthony, The reason is the same as the Serialization infrastructure. I work in a oodb and as soon as we instantiate the object we set its fields so calling constructors is at least waste of time/resources. In the worst cases we may have no viable constructor to use (all available constructors may throw when called with null/default values for its parameters)

Comment: @Quintin Robinson: basically we don't care if the class has any constructor at all. If possible it'd be better to just bypass calling any constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking into Android source code we found a way to achieve this by using ObjectInputStream#newInstance() static method.

```
private Object newInstanceSkippingConstructor(final Class clazz) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,     InvocationTargetException {

    Method newInstance = ObjectInputStream.class.getDeclaredMethod("newInstance", Class.class, Class.class);
    newInstance.setAccessible(true);
    return newInstance.invoke(null, clazz, Object.class);

}
```

Comment: Is this now out of date? I am using API 19 and there is no ObjectInputStream.newInstance(Class, Class) method as far as I can tell. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Hey, looking in Android source code looks like this method indeed got removed. Since I am not working with this code anymore I don't know if there's some alternative. The code in ObjectInputStream relies on Class.newInstance(), which based on the documentation, does calls ctors.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from native code with the JNI AllocObject function.  See [the JNI Spec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16337).  Calling out to native code is going to be more expensive than calling a no-op constructor, but probably cheaper than calling a constructor that throws an exception.

I don't know if there's another way to do it.  Nothing is leaping out at me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, however the Android platform does contain the Java Reflection API in `java.lang.reflect.*` so anything that is possible using the Java Reflection API is possible in Android

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that package but as I said, I could not find anything to achieve my goal :(

Answer (score 0):

I found out a library that can handle OBJ init with constructor bypass
http://objenesis.org/index.html
And they have different methods for different APIs.
There is a slight difference in their API 17 and 18+ impl as in the current suggested answer. Also Android N+ is using something called Unsafe that should be implemented by new JVMs http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/